# advices for restful web service url design using only http get and post

Tags: http, rest

or more specifically, please recommend me some name conventions for URIs designed to delete and update resources. What I am using is something like "POST resource/id/delete" and "POST resources/", but I am there must be better ways to do that. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML does not support HTTP DELETE, you can POST to the resource, say, `/resources/13` with a query string parameter to define the intent: `POST /resources/13?_method=DELETE HTTP/1.1`

In the case of updating a resource, you could do `POST resources/13?_method=PUT HTTP/1.1`, assuming of course that your intent will match the proper semantics of PUT, which is to place a complete and entire entity at the specified URI.

A very important thing to remember is that 'delete' is not a resource, and so it makes no sense to have a resource identifier for it. Delete is a verb, which is what HTTP methods are for. Of course, we can all hope that one day HTML will support HTTP entirely instead of just some arbitrary verbs.